# I cannot get anything to load onto the canvas with the create function in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I cannot get the images to preload

I have tried converting it to a url, I have tried copying the to the file in the project folder and I have tried just putting the file name.

```
function preload(){
  this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
  this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
  this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png');
  this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
} // preloads all of the files I will need to make the game
function create() {
  this.add.sprite(200, 200, 'star');
} // applies the files 
function update() {

}// update every frame




var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: {y:200},
      debug: false
    }
  },
scene: {
  preload,
  create,
  update
},

} // configures the game 

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

I would like to successfully display an image on the canvas, but it only shows a black box with some green lines on it. Any tips on how to fix this or what I am missing would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
    function preload() {
      this.load.image('sky', 'file:///home/chronos/u-fc7808c01e889e74148d1013b69f0a2241def976/Downloads/testprogram-atom.js/assets/sky.png');
      this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
      this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png');
      this.load.image('star', '/home/jojobinks/Desktop/testprogram-atom.js/star.png');
    }
    function create() {
      this.add.image(0, 0, 'sky');
    }
    function update() {

    }




    var config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: {y:200},
          debug: false
        }
      },
    scene: {
      preload,
      create,
      update
    },

    }

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.16.2/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your browsers Dev Tools and look at the Network requests. Is it actually loading the file in? Or do you have 404 errors there? Also, you can't load from `file://` and your game must be running from a web server. If you're just opening the index.html into your browser, it won't work. Please follow the Getting Started Guide on the Phaser site for more details.